# How to include headers from a third party package in Go?

Tags: go, header, include, cgo

Let's supose my package workspace has `github.com/yada/yada` third party package. Inside this package there is a `yoda.go.h` header I would like to reuse (not sure if it's a good idea, but that's a hole new question). How do I import the header from a dependecy package into my own package?

```
package main

// #cgo pkg-config: my-dep other-dep
// #include <someHeader.h>
// #include <otherHeader.h>
// #include github.com/yada/yada/yoda.go.h // doesn't work :(
import "C"
```

Apart from being a good idea or not, I still would like to know if it's possible.

PS: If you think it's really a bad idea, what should I do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CGO CFLAGS directive to reference additional include path.

```
//#cgo CFLAGS: -I $GOPATH/src/github.com/yada/yada/
...
//#include "yoda.go.h"
import "C"
```

**CORRECTION**:

The go tool does not expand $GOPATH variable during build. Instead, the full path should be used there. Corrected code:

```
//#cgo CFLAGS: -I /full/path/to/src/github.com/yada/yada/
//#include "yoda.go.h"
```

Comment: Hey, very smart. I'll accept this one since it addresses the question more directly, but both answers are very informative.

Comment: @marcioAlmada: ha, this is what I meant by referencing the header directly in the filesystem. Thought you had that all sorted out ;)

Comment: sorry @JimB I thought that "directly in the filesystem" meant to copy and paste the headers to somewhere with visibility xD

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a good idea to try and reference it directly, since it's not an exported entity, and is subject to change or removal.

If you really need that header, you'll have to reference it directly in your local filesystem. (of course you're free to copy into your project too)

Comment: The header is on a tagged release, so it seems safe to use.

Comment: I'm inclined to accept your answer (+1) and duplicate the header into my package... but before that, is there a way to include C code in GO without using a header file? (just inline it?)

Comment: It's up to you how safe you want to be with it. Since the header can't export anything there's no guarantee that it will reman as-is. It would be similar to using reflect to read out some un-exported values, which may change without affecting the public API.

Comment: you can put the C code directly in that cgo stanza if that helps: https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/cgo

Comment: Oh great, so inlining is possible. This seems to fit better with my use case. Thank you!